# Kivy window management

Tags: python, user-interface, gstreamer, kivy, xlib

I'm writing  gstreamer application and Iam using kivy as GUI framework.
Working with kivy I found out that it has poor window management so I wrote a module for window management using Xlib.
Now the thing is when I get ID of window and when I send it to gstreamer set_window_handle() function I don't get video rendered in kivy window nor there is a default gstreamer window.
I created a test GTK+ HelloWorld application which prints XID in the terminal and when I run it with my test script in which I call function from Xlib module in which I print ID of window I got 2 different values.
For example I get:
Gtk+ xid - 67108880
Xlib - 67108871 or I don't know some other random number as ID

Here is my code :

## Xlib module

```
class WManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.display=Display()
        self.WinIDs=self.display.screen().root.get_full_property(self.display.intern_atom('_NET_CLIENT_LIST'),X.AnyPropertyType).value

    def getWinID(self,name):
        for winID in self.WinIDs:
            wind=self.display.create_resource_object("window",winID)
            NAME = wind.get_wm_name()
            print(wind.get_wm_name(),":",winID)
            if name in NAME:
                return winID
```

## Functions where I call this module to get XID

```
  def on_sync_message(self, bus, msg):
    if msg.get_structure().get_name()=='prepare-window-handle':
        print('rendering area set')
        msg.src.set_window_handle(self.wid)



def on_play(self):
    X11Man=WManager()
    self.wid=X11Man.getWinID('main')
    self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
```

The thing I want to do is to get same ID with Xlib as GTK+ gets with `get_xid()` function

EDIT: 
Okey I realized that problem is not in window ID I can render video in any other window except that of kivy. What's the catch? How can I render it to kivy window? Which widget should I use?

Comment: I don't know if Kivy is a very good choice for doing multiple windows - Kivy is really better suited to single-paned apps, it's specifically designed for creating the same app for desktop+Android+iOS.

Comment: well I want to create application for Ubuntu Desktop enviroment that supports touch(multitouch optional) using python I tought kivy would be great for that but getting window id and sending it to gstreamer is a pain( I know kivy has built in gstreamer player but I don't need it I want to build complex pipeline).

Comment: @HarisKovacevic Once again, I will point out that you should use an appsink, just like Kivy does internally. Your video may very well be displayed using the code above, and as soon as GStreamer renders a frame to the window, Kivy will flip buffers and draw over it. You're making things way more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: Ryan can you suply me with example ? I would be really grateful to you

Comment: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx#L209

Comment: Bro this is bit to much for me as a begginer with python,kivy and gstreamer.If you could suply me with simple example where you create simple pipeline and render it to screen I'll accept your answer and I'll be really really grateful.

Comment: That IS a pretty simple example for using appsink in Python. Anything you're trying to do with a more complex pipeline will result in more complex code than what I linked.

Comment: I realize what are you talking and Iam kinda dissapointed I really wanted to use Kivy but I guess that's off the hook for now .I want you to give me your opinion on what should I use for GUI (python) that has good interaction with gstreamer and that has good touch screen support Iam aiming Ubuntu desktop enviroment(maybe MacOS and Windows) ?